# PHP function running inside loop not working (with code)

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, loops

I am running this function

```
function Age($month, $day, $year) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $dob = $month .''. $day .''. $year;
    $startDate = strtotime($dob);
    $endDate = time();
    $dif = $endDate - $startDate;

    return $years = (date('Y', $dif) - 1970) .' y, '. ($months = date('n', $dif) - 1).' m';
}
```

inside a `foreach` loop (some CodeIgniter markup):

```
foreach ($users as $row) {
    echo $this->includes->Age($row->birth_month, $row->birth_day, $row->birth_year)
  }
```

The loop works OK, showing all my users.

But the problem is that it calculates the age correctly for the first user and then shows that same age for all other users. I should point out that all other user's data is correct, only the age is wrong.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$dob` looks malformed. Try `$dob = $year . '-' . $month . '-' $day;`

Comment: `strtotime()` Doesn't like 'mm-dd-yyyy'

Answer (score 1):

You're missing space/separators.

```
$dob = $month .''. $day .''. $year;
```

should be

```
$dob = $month .'/'. $day .'/'. $year;
```

edit: 
Ambiguity. If using mm-dd-yyyy format, should be /

. and - indicate dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: This is not necessary, but if so, the best way is use mktime

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CI is caching the result?
Seems that function Age is correct

Comment: to my eyes CI is running the function (top code) and returning the values straight to the view (bottom code), so I just can't understand why it doesn't refresh the value for each loop

Comment: Oh.. try to use this foreach ($users as &$row)

Comment: `&$row` didn't work - tried @shad's suggestion above and fixed the issue (malformed date var)